Netsuite data replication to SQL Server
I am trying to move some data from Netsuite to SQL Server database for analytics purpose. I am using SSIS to build the ETL. I have used ODBC source and am able to pull all data for a table. Now I want to use the lastmodifieddate to extract only the modified data. How do I use a variable in the SQL command statement in ODBC source to do that. I am trying something like this but I have no idea how to map it to a variable.
Select * 
From Transaction 
Where LastModifiedDate > ?;

I want to use a variable in place of ? which will be updated from a different task before this task.
I am using Visual Studio 2022 with latest SSDT and SSIS package. My database is in Azure.

Have you tried any approach? and are you getting any error?

Basically you have to build a dynamic query (string data) into a variable from outside of the Data Flow Task. Then you use that variable as the source query in your ODBC Source task inside the Data Flow Task.
You would probably accomplish this by having an "Execute SQL Task" that stores the completed query into a string variable. The "Execute SQL Task" would allow you to define the input parameter, which you'd use to build the query string.
